# Map MySQL Database Columns to C# Objects?

Tags: c#, mysql, class, object, mapping

I am working on a project where I have a number of C# Objects held in a class like shown below:

```
public class DatabaseInfo
{
//Fields
public string info1 { get; set; }
public string info2 { get; set; }
public string info3 { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a database which will hold the value contained within this class within a Table called say "DatabaseInfo". I simply want to be able to easily map the Class Objects to the database fields so that I can pass the data from the object to the database, can anyone help??

Also I am using Visual Studio C# and MySQL.

Thanks

Comment: Try EntityFramework library. It is supplied with Visual Studio and .NET framework 4.0. With it's help you can easily create classes for all tables in database and leverage LINQ to do select/insert/update/delete operations. More reading here http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Tutorial_EF.html and here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx

Comment: You could use and Object/Relational-Mapper (ORM). See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6075364/880990.

Comment: Code First and POCO might be a goer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are talking about an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping).

You might want to look into Castle [ActiveRecord](http://castleproject.org/) (which is built on [nHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx)).

If you're using .NET 3.5 or 4.0, you can use the [.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) as well.

Personally, I prefer ActiveRecord since I like just being able to define mappings using attributes in code.  Entity Framework uses a mapping XML file (which can be modified using a GUI designer for Visual Studio) which I find a bit clunky (EF experts will probably chime in here about code first.)  Also, Entity Framework is very LINQ heavy, which is great if you like LINQ.  ActiveRecord uses a standard [ActiveRecord patern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern), or HQL, or LINQ - which gives you a bit more flexibility.

I won't go into too much detail as I figure there's already plenty of comparisons between these frameworks online.

I've used Entity Framework with both SQL Server and Oracle, and have found Oracle support generally works well, but probably doesn't get the same level of attention as SQL Server.  NHibernate has dialects for pretty much any RDBS you can think of, and I've found it to be a very mature and solid platform regardless of what DB you use.